# Decline a message in kafka use no-kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

By default in no-kafka there is a tentative configuration that defaults to 3.

```
return producer.send(messages, {
  retries: {
    attempts: 2,
    delay: {
      min: 100,
      max: 300
    }
  }
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-kafka

How can I manually decline a message?

```
var consumer = new Kafka.SimpleConsumer();

// data handler function can return a Promise
var dataHandler = function(messageSet, topic, partition) {
  messageSet.forEach(function(m) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    if (random > 5) {
      console.log(topic, partition, m.offset, m.message.value.toString("utf8"));
    } else {
        // Decline a message
      console.log("Decline a message");
    }
  });
};

return consumer.init().then(function() {
  // Subscribe partitons 0 and 1 in a topic:
  return consumer.subscribe("kafka-test-topic", [0, 1], dataHandler);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decline"?

Comment: I got a message, tried to execute a logic but it gave error. This document was not published again later.

Answer (score 0):

After the send method call,a separate thread is responsible for sending those batches of records to the appropriate kafka brokers. There is no control to cancel the records after the send call.We will get the response from the broker whether the message has been committed or not.

[image]